# App Engine import conflicts with grpc

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, python-import, grpc, google-app-engine-python

I'm having trouble with App Engine imports.

I need to have a Python App Engine (preferably standard) that manages grpc calls and can interact with Firebase

I've been able to make those two things work separately but combining them is giving me trouble.

I've created a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/bgirschig/9af74a202ec52593f8d855fb7ddb5dd5)

It contains a README with details on how to reproduce, with a **VERY** simple app.
There are 3 versions of the app in the gist:

- one with two conflicting imports (breaks down)
- one the the fist conflicting import alone (works)
- one the the second conflicting import alone (works)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is some issue with `six` lib support in GAE standard [[Github thread](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/5012)].

I used GAE flexible and it worked.

(app1.yaml code)

```
runtime: python-compat
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
env: flex

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main1.app

skip_files:
  - ^env$
  - ^(.*/)?.*\.pyc$
```

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to be able to keep App Engine standard (much faster deployment times, better scaling, etc...) but it looks like I might not have a choice.